# Need Help - Simple Random Number Generator using Auto Hot Key Script

Tags: random, numbers, generator, autohotkey

I've read the documentation for Auto Hot Key, but am new to writing scripts. I keep getting errors.

I want a very simple script - so when I use a hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> - Autohotkey creates a random number that is:

3 Digits - Decimal - 8 Digits

With the very first digit of the first group being between 1 and 4.

The rest can be completely random.

Off the sample scripts I tried to edit one posted - but I am doing something wrong. If anyone could help it would be really appreciated!

The output should look like this:    314.99382028     The first number always between 1 and 4, the rest random, and decimal always the 4th character.

Then, it should just paste the number to where ever you currently are within windows - not pop up display.

Thanks for anyone who could take a quick look and help out.

Rocket

```
^!n:: ;<-- change this if you want a diff hotkey
Chars1 = 1234
Chars2 = 1234567890
Chars3 = .
str =
clipboard =
UpperRange = 3 ;<-- use all 3 character strings
len = 12 ;<-- number of characters in the number

; generate a new number
loop, %len%
{ random,x,1,%UpperRange% ;<-- selects the Character string
random,y,1,26 ;<-- selects the character in the string
if (x = 12) ; if numeric there are only 10 digits
}
{ random,y,1,10
StringMid,z,Chars%x%,1 ;<-- grab the selected letter
str = %str%%z% ;<-- and add it to the number string
}
clipboard = %str% ;<-- put the completed string on the clipboard
Clipwait ;<-- wait for the clipboard to accept the string`
```

**AND THEN PASTE WHERE EVER MY CURSOR IS - Not sure how to do that.**

Thanks so much for the help!

Rocket

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job if I understood it correctly:

```
^!n::
    SendInput, % "{LButton}" . RandomString(1,"1234") . RandomString(2) . "." . RandomString(8)
Return

RandomString(length,chars:="0123456789") {
    charsCount := StrLen(chars)
    Loop % length {
        Random, num, 1, % StrLen(chars)
        string .= SubStr(chars,num,1)
    }
    Return string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your answer on your clipboard, you could simply use:

```
Send, ^v
```

This will paste where your caret is, not your mouse cursor, so if you want to paste where your mouse cursor is, just add Click before....

```
Click
Sleep, 30
Send, ^v
```